# Are there surveillance cameras in aircraft cargo bays?

Tags: aircraft-design, airbus, ground-operations, boeing, camera

I've heard that there are cameras on the fuselage and wings of some passenger aircraft. Is there a similar surveillance system in-built at the cargo bay/compartment of a passenger aircraft?

During the baggage loading / unloading of passenger aircraft, many burglary events can be experienced. I think that if there was a camera surveillance system, theft could be reduced significantly. At the same time, when the fire warning was received from the compartment, the pilot could confirm by monitoring the cargo compartment whether the warning was correct and avoid unnecessarily diverting. In addition, the perpetrators of compartment damage occurring in cargo loading / offloading could also be easily identified.

Why did the aircraft manufacturers not consider installing in-built cameras in the cargo compartment?

Comment: *"the pilot could confirm by monitoring the cargo compartment whether the warning was correct and avoid unnecessarily diverting"* It could be in a part they can't see, as a pilot I would divert regardless of seeing it on a camera or not. A little spark can [quickly turn into an inferno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigeria_Airways_Flight_2120). As soon as smoke filled the compartment, it would be useless. I'm also not sure they would thwart thefts (as rare as they are) because there are a lot of places to hide or steal before luggage gets to the aircraft.

Comment: If there is nothing to be seen due to smoke, a real fire warning has been confirmed via using the camera, isn’t it?

Comment: Right, but what has it bought you other than a distraction? You have an alarm going off and no reason to mistrust it. Why do you need the pilot, who is flying the plane, trying to coordinate an emergency landing, to also need to visually verify an alarm?

Comment: You need to have a camera that is very sensitive to smoke in order to detect small fires quickly... you want to do it by looking at light being absorbed or scattered by smoke... that device is exactly a photoelectric smoke detector which is what they already put in.

Comment: One good additional question would be "what is the purpose of cameras fitted on some aircrafts?" All those I know of (only the A380) are mainly here to help taxiing.

Comment: *During the baggage loading / unloading of passenger aircraft, many burglary events can be experienced*  [citation needed]

Comment: @RonBeyer High humidity can also cause a spurious warnings or the smoke detection system can create false alarm without an actual fire/smoke. This kind of fake indications can be accomplished with the use of integrated hold survelliance systems.

Comment: @GolfCharlie But how often do these happen that we would need an entire new system installed in every airplane? 1 in a million flights? 1 in 10 million? Doesn't the distraction/cost/complexity/weight outweigh the benefits of diverting the "one in a year" flight (even if it were per-airline) for a false alarm?

Comment: @RonBeyer The main benefit of the camera system would be to reveal who carried out damage in the cargo hold rather than using it to verify the fire. In plane damages found on arrival costs airlines a lot and it’s not an easy thing to find out who caused the damage.

Comment: I'm still not sure that is useful, but I won't spam this post with more comments about it. The damages that do occur in the aircraft usually occur during flight, not loading. Damages during loading are more bound to happen on the way to the plane, than in the plane itself.

Answer (score 1):

Any burglary of cargo would happen outside the aircraft, after unloading the cargo. External cameras on the ramp are much more effective for this purpose. I don't know of any aircraft that has internal cameras just for the cargo area.